# fread failing C program

Tags: c, file, fread

```
double buf[1000];
double value;
double *ptr = &value;
for(i=0; i < no_of_iterations; i++) {
  for(j=0; j < chunkSize; j++) {
    num_bytes_read = fread(ptr,1,pcm_sample_size,fptr); //read one sample
    if(num_bytes_read == 2) {
      sum_sq += (*ptr) * (*ptr); //calculate power of each sample
      buf[j] = *ptr;
    }
    else {
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!flag) {
    printf("exiting loop");
    break;
  }
  power = sum_sq/chunkSize;//calculate rms value of signals for chunkSize samples
  if(power < threshold) //compare with some value
    printf("power is lower than threshold"); //silence-don't write
  else { //write
    ret = fwrite(buf,1,pcm_sample_size,optr);
    if(ret != 1) 
      printf("error in fwrite %d", ret);
  }
 }
printf("done");
fclose(fptr);
fclose(optr);
```

Above is my code for writing some pcm samples to a file depending on some condition but I'm getting fread error. 
The control does not enter the if(num_bytes_read==2) block. I think the error is because I want to read pcm samples which are 2 bytes in size and I need somewhere to store it. What datatype can I use to store a 2 byte pcm value(the pcm value is not an int value). 
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
num_bytes_read = fread(ptr,1,pcm_sample_size,fptr);//read one sample
```

ptr is pointing to the address of value so it must be `sizeof(double)` and 1, as you read in just one value.

The result of an fread is the number of items read, not the number of bytes.

Are you initialising `sum_sq` where you need to?

To read 2 doubles:

```
double readbuf[2];
num_items_read = fread( readbuf, sizeof(double), 2, fptr );
if( num_items_read == 2 )
{
    covariance_sum += readbuf[0] * readbuf[1];
}
```

Not sure exactly what you are trying to multiply, but obviously if it is 2 different values it is not a "square". I will let you fix your code to your actual logic.

Comment: I need the second and third arguments to be the same. So, how can I change ptr so that it is a variable of size 2 bytes? ok point noted and yes I have initialized sum_sq to 0.0

Comment: It's fread(membuf, sizeof_item, num_items, fptr). You are reading 1 double so it should be fread(ptr, sizeof(double), 1, fptr). It will only ever return 1 or 0 in your case.

Comment: Oops, yes you are right. But the output file is still of 0 bytes

Comment: The application crashes in the middle. What do I do?

Comment: Debug it. You could do that via a log file, writing information as it goes along to trace what it is doing.

Comment: The problem is with fread. Could you please take a look at the edited question.